# How to format number input in react native where there is one number per box for 6 boxes?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am building an app with react native and I am trying to get the number input formatted like this where there is one integer per box. The cursor also is in the next box and the boxes that have been filled have a larger border. Any thoughts would help.

[image: 6 boxes with no numbers]

[image: 6 boxes with 3 boxes filled]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try [react-native-otp-form](https://github.com/abdymm/react-native-otp-form)

```
import {OTP} from 'react-native-otp-form';

<OTP
    codeCount={6}
    containerStyle={{marginTop: 50}}
    otpStyles={{backgroundColor: '#eee'}}
/>
```